# JSONDecodeError on Python Pub/Sub Script

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, runtime-error, google-cloud-pubsub

Here is my Full Code. This script is triggered by a pub/sub in cloud functions, and parses out the message from the pub/sub by key, and value. for testing I have a sample string as the message in the code.

```
import base64
import os
import json
#import subprocess
#import shlex

    def hello_pubsub(event, context):
        """Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
        Args:
             event (dict): Event payload.
             context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
        """
        pubsub_message ='{"name": instance1, "zone": us-west1-c, "project": projectname}'
        pubsub_json = json.loads(pubsub_message)
        for key,value in pubsub_json.items():
              print (key,value)



    hello_pubsub('event', 'context')
```

However, when I run this, I get this error

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 10 (char 9)
```

Using debugger in VSCode, the error gets trigger by the json.loads line.

I have tried using different versions of json.loads and Im not sure why I get this error, when I use json.dumps I get a sting/integers error. Any Ideas?

Comment: Your JSON is not properly quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed not valid JSON. The strings need to be quoted:

```
pubsub_message ='{"name": "instance1", "zone": "us-west1-c", "project": "projectname"}'
```

I can't really understand what this is trying to test though.

Comment: I need to parse out name, zone, and project into 3 separate variables, so this is a test to see wether it can be parsed.

Comment: Also this answer worked. Thank you! sorry if it was a stupid question as I am new